# Is there any way to append text with jQuery only to the same div

Tags: jquery, html

Im making a comment system. I have a div with some smiley-images. Everytime an image is clicked the image text will be appended to the textarea. But the problem is that everytime i click on an smiley-image then it will append text to all the textareas on the page because all the teaxtareas have the the same class. I have also tried to give an id to the textarea but then it would only append text to the first teatarea

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="appendpostid(' :3 ')">
    <img src="emotions/fb/colonthree.gif" class="smiley">
</a>

<textarea class="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
```

And the jQuery script:

```
<script>
    function appendpostid( postid ) {
        $('.comment').val($('.comment').val() + postid);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you'd have to add an id to the textarea, then it seems fairly obvious from there...

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you want to have many sets of these buttons and textareas. In this case, one option is to select the textarea for the button using the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method, which selects the next element in the DOM. You can target this by using the `.comment` class as a selector.

In this example I've also modified your HTML slightly to put the post ID in as a data attribute, and applied a class that you can use to bind the click event using jQuery:

```
<a href="#" data-post-id=" :3 " class="appender">
    <img src="emotions/fb/colonthree.gif" class="smiley"/>
</a>
```

Then your jQuery:

```
$('.appender').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    $(this).next('.comment').append(postId);
});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/nzuzrraL/1/) with multiple sets of this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="appendpostid(e, this,' :3 ')">
    <img src="emotions/fb/colonthree.gif" class="smiley">
</a>

<textarea class="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
```

and jquery

```
<script>
    function appendpostid(e, elem, postid ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var textElem = $(elem).next('.comment');
        textElem.val(textElem.val() + postid);
    }
</script>
```